# constructor overloading. Getting the wrong solution

Tags: c++

```
  #include <iostream> 
  #include <conio.h>

  using namespace std;

  class Crectangle {
      int * height, * width;
      public: Crectangle();
      Crectangle(int, int);
      Crectangle();
      int area() {
          return (*height * *width);
      }
  };

  Crectangle::Crectangle() {
      *height = 3;
      *width = 5;
  }
  Crectangle::Crectangle(int a, int b) {
      height = new int;
      width = new int;
      *height = a;
      *width = b;
  }
  Crectangle::~Crectangle() {
      delete height;
      delete width;
  }

  int main() {
      Crectangle rect(1, 2);
      Crectangle rectb;
      cout << "rect = " << rect.area() << "\n";
      cout << "rectb = " << rectb.area();

      getch();
  }
```

I am getting area for rect to be "6", instead of "2".  Can someone please point out the mistake.

Comment: Why are height and width pointers? Your default constructor is wrong as it will never allocate space for the height or width. Just use ints directly, and if you want default values, just use `Crectangle::Crectangle(int a = 3, int b = 5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of your constructors allocates memory for width and height. The other one has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Crectangle::Crectangle()
{
  *height=3; // height could point anywhere
  *width=5;  // width could point anywhere
}
```

you are dereferencing pointers that are not initialized. This is undefined behaviour, so the result could be anything.

The solution is to not use pointers for `height` and `width`. There seems to be no reason whatsoever to use them.

```
class Crectangle
{
    int height;
    int width;
 ....
};
```

Comment: ya, i know, i could have done the thing without using pointers, but I just wanted to do it by using them. Thanks anyways, now I know where i was wrong.

Comment: If you're using pointers, you must either implement or disable assignment (operator=), too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Crectangle {
int * height, * width;
public: 
Crectangle();
Crectangle(int, int);
Crectangle();
int area() {
               return (*height * *width);
           }
};

Crectangle::Crectangle() {

   height = new int;
   width = new int;
  *height = 3;
  *width = 5;
}

Crectangle::Crectangle(int a, int b) {
  height = new int;
  width = new int;
  *height = a;
  *width = b;
}

Crectangle::~Crectangle() {
  delete height;
  delete width;
}

int main()
{
    Crectangle rect(1, 2);
    Crectangle rectb;
    cout << "rect = " << rect.area() << "\n";
    cout << "rectb = " << rectb.area();

    getch();
}
```